# function of rdi register during sys_exit syscall

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, system-calls

I have isolated the sys_exit call to the following instruction on my machine

```
xorq %%rdi, %%rdi  /* return value */
movq $60, %%rax
syscall
```

What is the purpose of the rdi resister in this case? What is this sys call expected to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the `exit` call, rdi is it's argument, the exit status. In C programs this is usually what's returned from `main`, which could explain the comment.

You can check [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) the calling convention used in system calls for some architectures.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I checked the syscall table for linux and this makes sense.